# Javascript form validation. Street Number. How to set accepted numbers to 1 but accept numbers 1-99999

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble with some JS form validation.

I've linked a external .JS script in my html head section with function rules.

I have the following function rule in the .JS script file:

```
  function IsValid5DigitStreetNumber( str ) {
    // Return immediately if an invalid value was passed in
    if (str+"" == "undefined" || str+"" == "null" || str+"" == "")  
        return false;

    var isValid = true;

    str += "";

    // Rules: zipstr must be 5 characters long, and can only contain numbers from
   // 0 through 9
   if (IsBlank(str) || (str.length != 1) || !IsInt(str, false))
        isValid = false;

   return isValid;
}
```

I have the following JS code in my html head section

```
    if(IsValid5DigitStreetNumber(document.orderbooks.querySelectorAll("[name=streetnumber]")[0].value)) {
  } else {
    alert("Street Name invalid! Please enter a valid 1-99999 digit street number!:");
    return false;
  }
```

It's throwing up the alert message every time even when I enter a correct number.

I want to be able to accept a number between 1 and 99999 in the html form for street number. What do I change to get it working?

Comment: It's testing for `str.length` being 1. You'd definitely need to remove that condition

Comment: Have you debugged this by checking what the result of `document.orderbooks.querySelectorAll("[name=streetnumber]")` is? Is it really finding something for that selector?

Comment: You're doing many strange checks, considering that HTML form controls can only contain text. Also, we don't know what `IsBlank()` or `IsInt()` look like. (Side note: in my country, street addresses don't necessarily have a number.)

Comment: `undefined` and  `null` are not strings, though you never need to check these, the value of an input will always be a string.

Comment: You say that the number must be 5 digits long but you also say that it can be 1. Those are contradictory statements. Do you mean a **maximum** of 5 digits long?

Comment: "_to accept a number between 1 and 99999_" is probably the final question with correct conditions?

Comment: Yes it needs to accept a number between 1 and 99999 for the street number and be maximum of 5 digits but can also be 1 digit, 2 digits, 3 digits, 4 digits..

Comment: Why not `if (Number.isInteger(num) && num > 0 && num < 1e5) /* num is ok */`?

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

After determining requirements at last:

```
function IsValid5DigitStreetNumber( str ) {
  if (!/^\d{1,5}$/.test(str)) {
    return false;
  }
  const num = parseInt(str, 10);
  return num >= 1 && num < 1e5;
}
```

Comment: The question says that `0` isn't valid.

Comment: Hm, you're right, although the comment in the code says "0 through 9" :)

Comment: Neither of your regular expressions are correct. Both require 5 digits (so "1" would not be accepted), and the second one would not accept "10000" for instance.

Comment: Yeah your function code requires 5 digits to be entered to be successful.  It needs to accept a number between 1 and 99999 for the street number and be maximum of 5 digits but can also be 1 digit, 2 digits, 3 digits, or 4 digits at the same time..

Comment: @c0nfus3d Updated my answer.